# AzureIoTHubClient wrapper framework could not build module

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, cocoapods, azure-iot-hub

I'm trying to create framework project (Wrapper for AzureIoTHubClient).
Please find the below Podfile in the Framework xcode project,

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

def app_and_tests_common_pods()
  pod 'AzureIoTUtility', '=1.5.0', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'AzureIoTuMqtt', '=1.5.0', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'AzureIoTuAmqp', '=1.5.0', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'AzureIoTHubClient', '=1.5.0', :modular_headers => true
end

target 'Wrapper' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Wrapper
  app_and_tests_common_pods()

  target 'WrapperTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
    app_and_tests_common_pods()
  end

end
```

Please find the Podspec for the Framework project,

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name                     = 'Wrapper'
  s.version                  = '1.0.0'
  s.platform                 = :ios, '9.0'
  s.summary                  = 'Library for Azure IoT Hub Client Wrapper'
  s.source_files             = 'Wrapper/**/*.{h,swift}'
  s.platform                 = :ios
  s.ios.deployment_target    = '9.0'
  s.dependency               'AzureIoTUtility', '1.5.0'
  s.dependency               'AzureIoTuMqtt', '1.5.0'
  s.dependency               'AzureIoTuAmqp', '1.5.0'
  s.dependency               'AzureIoTHubClient', '1.5.0'
  s.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'arm64' }
  s.user_target_xcconfig = { 'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'arm64' }
end
```

Please find the Podfile for the iPhone project,

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

def app_and_tests_common_pods()
  pod 'AzureIoTUtility', '=1.5.0', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'AzureIoTuMqtt', '=1.5.0', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'AzureIoTuAmqp', '=1.5.0', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'AzureIoTHubClient', '=1.5.0', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'Wrapper', :path => '../Wrapper', :modular_headers => true
end

target 'SampleApp' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for SampleApp
  app_and_tests_common_pods()

end

target 'SampleAppTests' do
  inherit! :search_paths
  # Pods for SampleApp
  app_and_tests_common_pods()
  
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
  end
end
```

When I try to build the Framework project, it gets build successfully, when I try to build the iPhone app project, I get the following errors in the Framework project where I have imported the ***AzureIoTHubClient***,

> Could not build Objective-C module 'AzureIoTHubClient'
> Header 'agenttypesystem.h' not found

[image]
[image]

And below warnings

> Skipping 'agenttypesystem.h' because module declaration of 'AzureIoTHubClient' lacks the 'framework' qualifier

How to resolve these issues?
Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Did you check this quickstart in the official documentation and is it working for you? Wondering if this quickstart can help understand what may be the issue here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/iot-hub/quickstart-send-telemetry-ios

Comment: Using the Quickstart guide, I was able to integrate into the iOS project, but I'm facing the above issue only with the Framework project

Comment: I see you also added an issue here, will try to bring attention to it: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-iot-samples-ios/issues/18